# How to use a repeat with a hexadecimal escape with a bash regex operator

Tags: regular-expression, posix

I've been struggling for days to try and get something seemingly simple to work.

```
(LC_ALL=POSIX; regex="src\\.[\\x20-\\x7E]+\\.system"; file="src.dirtree.system";
 if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
```

The desire is to match src.*.system where the * can be anything in the character range `\x21-\x7E`. If I wanted `\x20-\x7E` then `[ -~]+` works, but how can I get this range to work or any arbitrary hexadecimal escape range with repeats `*, + or {x,y}`?

Bash version is `4.3.11(1)-release` and no I cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

A look at the Bash documentation refers `man 3 regex` for details:

> An additional binary operator, ‘`=~`’, is available, with the same
>   precedence as ‘`==`’ and ‘`!=`’. When it is used, the string to the
>   right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and
>   matched accordingly (as in *regex* 3)).

[`man 3 regex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regex.3.html) on Linux indicates that these are POSIX regexes, which is confirmed by the description of [the configure flag](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Optional-Features) needed to enable this:

> `--enable-cond-regexp`
>   Include support for matching POSIX regular expressions using the
>   ‘`=~`’ binary operator in the `[[` conditional command. (see
>   [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)).

And `man 7 regex`, which describes the syntax, says:

> With the exception 
>          of these and some combinations using '[' (see next paragraphs), all
>          other special characters, including '\', lose their special
>          significance within a bracket expression.

And makes no mention of hexadecimal byte ranges. So I'd say this is not directly possible.

---

You could abuse [the ANSI C quoting feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to substitute the actual bytes from their hex versions:

```
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex="src\.["$'\x21-\x7E'"]+\.system"; file='src.dir!ree.system';  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
yes
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex="src\.["$'\x21-\x7E'"]+\.system"; file='src.dir ree.system';  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
no
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex="src\.["$'\x21-\x7E'"]+\.system"; file="src.dirtree.system";  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
yes
```

Note how `regex` is the concatenation of three strings: `"src\."`, `$'\x21-\x7E'` (which gets expanded to the corresponding bytes) and `"]+\.system"`.

---

Though, of course, for this case you could have juste used `!-~`, properly quoted:

```
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex='src\.[!-~]+\.system'; file='src.dirtree.system';  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
yes
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex='src\.[!-~]+\.system'; file='src.dir!ree.system';  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
yes
$ (LC_ALL=POSIX; regex='src\.[!-~]+\.system'; file='src.dir ree.system';  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi;)
no
```

Or `[[:graph:]]`, which I think should be the same range for ASCII characters.

Comment: I settled on graph, but it is a truly disgusting solution. And yes I was quite aware of the manual and how it indicates these are POSIX ERE regexes. My locale also seems to break them though (en_NZ.UTF-8) and I need to use LC_ALL=C or POSIX to get it to work. Another thing worth checking was `set -o | grep posix`.